# Is there a word or slang word to call a girl who loves brand products?

Tags: word-request, slang

Is there a word or slang expression for girls who are preoccupied with materialistic things, such as bags, rings, necklaces and so on, and with showing such things off to others?

Girls for whom superficial appearance is more important than internal qualities.

Comment: Fanboy immediately springs to mind. Does fangirl work?

Comment: When you say "brand products", do you mean products that have a distinctive logo, so that anyone can read the brand name?

Comment: In fact, I meant to focus on pursuiting materialistic things only, not related to any brand name, even though we should find its value. that is, a girl obsessed about looks.

Comment: By "girls" do you mean females, generally? Do you mean females below a certain age or stage in life? To some people, using "girl" to mean "woman" may seem offensive. See [this](http://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/may/27/is-the-word-girl-offensive), for example

Comment: @JimReynolds While on the other hand, many adult women refer to themselves as "girls" and like to be called "girls". One example that may be familiar to users of this site: Grammar Girl, http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/grammar-girl. It appears she made up this title for herself and is proud of it.

Comment: @Jay. Certainly.

Comment: "Valley girl"? Seems like what I recall. Maybe a bit out of date.

Comment: She's a "clothes horse" would suggest a certain amount of attraction to branded fashion clothes..

Comment: Reminds me of Drake's ["Fancy"](http://genius.com/Drake-fancy-lyrics)

Comment: 'society conscious' could be an option. These guys are more into 'how do they look/appear' to the society.

Comment: this is called being *basic*!

Comment: I called her Amy.  Isn't this entirely opinion based?

Comment: "shallow" does the trick

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word "poser" comes to mind.

There are a few words and phrases that generally mean this sort of thing but usually they refer to a specific aspect. Someone who overly values worldly possessions would be "materialistic" but a materialistic person may or may not have the motivation to show off those possessions. They may simply be a hoarder or even secretive about their possessions.

Someone who likes to show off could be "vain", "pretentious" or compensating for insecurities but that may also apply to someone who pulls stunts for attention or someone who tries to "win" every conversation.

"Shallow" is another broad term that encompasses most of what you describe.

Comment: as soon as I see the word 'Poser' in your answer, I could remember what I have seen in every place.  one of the perfect matches.

Comment: Note a poser poses with stuff that is not neccessarily of a respected brand. He/she just shows off with stuff, to be admired. You asked for a fan addicted to brands, which imho would be a different thing. You can show off (and pose, i.e. be a poser, with) cheap Rolex clones, or ugly sportscars tuned to the absurd, without ever giving any indication of valueing the original brand like Rolex, Porsche, Ferrari, or whatever, which would be more important to a person addicted to brands.

Comment: You wont impress as many people with a knock off as you will with the real thing which is ultimately what a poser would care about. Its not about the brands, its about the attitude.

Comment: No, a "poser", to me, is someone who acts or dresses like someone they're not.  This could be hanging around a ski hill with expensive, professional gear but not really knowing how to ski at all - just enjoying *looking* like a pro for the attention.  Same with someone at a skate park with a killer skateboard but who would fall on their face if they actually tried to ride it.  Could be someone with pro-photography gear looking the part but actually taking awful snapshot photos - just enjoying looking like someone with skills but not actually having them.

Answer (score 31):

*(vulgar slang alert)*

> fashion whore

*A preachy know it all under a skin of designer clothing. Criticizes everything she considers "out of style" or "tacky".* <sub>[(from the Urban Dictionary)](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fashion+whore)</sub>

As @J.R. says: use this term with caution.

Comment: In case our learners don't understand what you mean by "slang alert," I'll elaborate here. This is a _slang_ term, and some would think that it borders on vulgar slang. This suggestion has its place; it could be used among friends who are unlikely to misconstrue the words as insulting, and understand them in context. However, this would be a very risky phrase to use in a professional environment, and probably shouldn't be used around people that you don't know very well, particularly in mixed company.

Comment: I think this expression is almost the closest answer to look for. And I am sure this vulgar slang is educative for learner like me. I'm gonna use at my caution. :)

Comment: Stealing from German "Markenjünger", your answer inspires "brand disciple". Would that be understood, with a grin?

Comment: @TheBlastOne "Brand loyalist" would be a better phrase.

Comment: This and 'brand whore' are the most immediate responses in my mind

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer. More votes, more acceptance.

Comment: @JuanCarlosCoto thanks, but that is not how this site works. The accepted answer is the answer which is the most useful for the [OP](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/what-does-op-mean), probably the answer he ended up using. There is even a [badge](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/populist) for these kind of situations.

Comment: Another variant that was the first to my mind based on the phrase "loves brand products" in the question: [label whore](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=label+whore)

Answer (score 20):

It's hard to come up with a word that works all the time, because much of this depends on your perspective.

Some might call this person ***shallow***. They think this person pays too much money for a name brand – particularly if they don't have a lot of [disposable income](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/disposable-income?a=british). They might view this person as a sucker for a slick advertising campaign, and as a person who succumbs to peer pressure.

> **[shallow](https://www.wordnik.com/words/shallow)** (*adj.*) Concerned mainly with superficial matters.

However, people who enjoy trendy fashions might call this same person ***sophisticated***. They regard this person as someone who has good tastes in fashion, as someone who likes to wear well-made, stylish [accessories](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+are+fashion+accessories).

> **[sophisticated](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sophisticated)** (*adj*) Having obtained worldly experience; cosmopolitan.
>   Elegant, refined.

---

Your question says this, which makes me think that maybe you're looking for the former term:

> I mean to like external looks more than internal value

but not everyone sees this emphasis on the external as a negative thing.

---

Another phrase that could work is ***material girl***, made popular by a Madonna song by the same name:

> **[material girl](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/material-girl?r=66)** (*n.*) a woman or girl mainly concerned with material things

Material girl could be regarded as a trendy way to call a woman *materialistic*, which means she has a preoccupation with worldly goods, such as expensive clothes and fancy cars.

Comment: Stylish resonates with me here - it makes me think of "style over substance". Now if I could just think of the word I call folks that value style over substance...

Comment: @ColleenV - Agreed; _stylish_ is an interesting word in this discussion. If I said of a coworker, "She is a stylish dresser," that might mean crisp business suits from [Ann Taylor](http://richmedia.channeladvisor.com/ImageDelivery/imageService?profileId=52000652&id=557419&recipeName=pdlg488x601). I might have to say she is "overly stylish" to communicate a less-than-healthy obsession.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestion according to several cases. I think the "material girl" is a decent fit here. :)

Comment: I feel sorry for picking up only one as answers.

Comment: @GTKim - Don't worry about it. Quite often, a lot of good answers is the sign of a great question. Thanks for asking such an interesting question.

Answer (score 11):

The first thing that springs to mind is [fashionista](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fashionistas): *a person who follows trends in the fashion industry obsessively and strives continually to adopt the latest fashions*. Some see fashionista as a positive description, and some see it as somewhat negative, so context is important. Anyone who felt fashion was a somewhat silly and [shallow](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/shallow) pursuit would think of fashionista as negative.

Another term is [brand-conscious](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/brand-conscious): *aware of popular ​brands and wanting to ​buy particular ​brands rather than others*. This isn't really used that much in informal speech with friends. It's more likely to be used in a news article about "brand-conscious" teens needing expensive sneakers or jeans.

Comment: Hmmm, Fashionista is too good for my sense which I am looking for. I mean something in a negative sense. :)

Answer (score 11):

[Materialistic](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin0cbcyv3KAhWB56YKHW3DDcoQFgg3MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdictionary.reference.com%2Fbrowse%2Fmaterialistic&usg=AFQjCNE-MsoM-w6KtbUVs9XodaxId7wTbQ&bvm=bv.114195076,d.dGY) seems fit

> **adjective**
>
> 1. excessively concerned with physical comforts or the acquisition of wealth and material possessions, rather than with spiritual,
>      intellectual, or cultural values.
> 2. adhering to the philosophy of **materialism**, a theory that regards matter as constituting the universe and all its phenomena.

See also [materialism](https://www.google.com.ph/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=materialistic)

[image]

Comment: Nice picture. I´m glad nobody will remember me for the stuff that owned me.

Answer (score 9):

"Fashionista" is a less insulting term for a girl - although if she's eighteen or over you should call her a woman - who buys and wears designer clothing and accessories.

It would however not be a good fit for a woman or girl who wears expensive purses or shoes but doesn't wear designer clothes, or one who doesn't buy a new wardrobe at least twice a year. A fashionista changes her wardrobe with the season, is always up-to-date, and is dressed from head to foot in the latest fashions.

Comment: "Fashion victim" is similar.

Answer (score 7):

**Brand junkie** seems to convey the meaning quite nicely (hey, it's an addiction!) without being too vulgar.

Comment: To me, this appears to be the most appropriate answer. "Poser" has been accepted, but it's the wrong term for what the question asked for.

Comment: I prefer a vulgar word, because someone who asked me is wanting. :)

Answer (score 5):

For a modern slang term, and depending on the quality / desirability / rarity of the products, she could be described as **basic**.

"**Basic** is a slang term in American popular culture used to pejoratively describe people who like popular, mainstream products or music." [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_bitch)

> "Gucci Gucci, Louis Louis, Fendi Fendi, Prada / Basic bitches wear that shit so I don't even bother." - [Kreayshawn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WJFjXtHcy4)

Comment: yeah, Basic or Basic bi-ches are also sutiable word that I look for. :)

Comment: @UtherKim use bi-ches with caution. It's not a good word

Comment: 'basic' in this sense is extremely US-centric. It's meaningless in the UK to anyone who isn't up to date on US slang, I've no idea what Canadians, Australians etc. make of it.

Comment: Basic:  I was wondering why there was no mention of BWB which is common slang in the U.S. to describe exactly what the OP was asking.

Answer (score 5):

> brand whore

This is about as offensive as what @Glorfindel came up with. The difference is that it implies loyalty to specific brands rather than fashion in general. 
There's also an opposite meaning that the person is working for that brand to raise its profile.

Comment: Interesting. "Brand slut", by contrast, appears to indicate somebody who easily switches brands and is not loyal to one.

Answer (score 3):

Some great answers have been posted, the majority of which are generally not offensive. Here are a few more slang terms that are common but provocative and insulting, and as such should never be said directly to the person they are meant to describe unless your explicit intent is to insult them. You should also only use these terms among friends in an informal environment.

> **[Valley Girl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yx70THjsTvU&t=2m8s)**
>   Invoking the stereotype of a shallow, unintelligent rich
>   girl who is probably spray-tanned orange and has nothing better to do
>   than drive around town in daddy's convertible buying high fashion
>   items with daddy's credit card. The "Valley" comes from the origin of
>   this stereotype, the Valley in southern California.
>
> **Bimbo**
>   A girl who is attractive because she's exceedingly obsessed
>   with being perfectly groomed and adorned in high fashion and glamorous
>   accessories. However, she has a personality that makes a puddle seem
>   deep, as the total sum of her life goals are to sexualize and
>   objectify herself for the purpose of being desired.

Since I feel a slight tingle of sexism being a man and writing this answer, here are some terms to describe men in the same way, some negative, just to balance the scales:

> **Metrosexual**
>   Abnormal (as in above average) interest fashion for a male, overly concerned with self image.
>
> **Player**
>   A player is a male who, among other things, focuses
>   intensely on his own image due to the the desire to appear wealthy and
>   sexualize himself for his adventures in manipulating others, primarily
>   people of the opposite sex. This is not a nice thing to be called,
>   because it generally means you're sleazy and untrustworthy.
>
> **GQ**
>   GQ is the title of a popular magazine for men, fully named
>   "Gentlemen Quarterly". This magazine is known for featuring well
>   dressed, well groomed men. Calling someone "GQ" is generally a
>   compliment in recognition of their taste in and use of fashion.

Comment: good suggestions. but as I am not a US resident, I wonder if you are using the above slangs commonly in daily use.

Comment: @UtherKim - It's true that these terms are all widely recognized in the U.S., and may not be so well-known in other parts of the English-speaking world. Maybe someone from the UK or Australia can comment; I'd be interested to hear their perspective.

Comment: Thanks J.R. The valley girl is pretty close to what I look for. :)

Comment: I'm Canadian and this is a common expression for this type of person. The connection to the Valley in CA doesn't really matter and in fact, I didn't know that was the origin of the "Valley" portion until I googled it for example etc for this answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

label whore

> someone who only wears brand name clothes

further reading:
http://therefinedpursuit.com/2011/10/label-whore-vs-label-lover/

Answer (score 2):

**Brand Loyalty**

I'm surprised that nobody has come up with this one yet. I'm a guy, and we use this to refer to guys in the same situation, and I think it'd apply to girls also.

> He's got Nike shoes, a Nike shirt, Nike socks, a Nike backpack, he really has **brand loyalty.**

Comment: A good suggestion, but she can be addicted to not only a brand but also materials. I think Brand Loyalty emphasizes about brand.

Answer (score 2):

You might call such a person a **aficionado**.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aficionado

> an ardent devotee; fan, enthusiast.

We often use this word to describe someone who is especially interested in something niche. You might describe this girl as a **"brand aficionado"**.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. (By itself, I think _aficionado_ might be a little too broad, but qualifying it with _brand_ makes this an excellent suggestion.)

Answer (score 2):

"Label queen" can apply to both sexes, and isn't TOO insulting.

Answer (score 1):

Preps? That's what we called whoever had all the top brand clothing.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the term **glamour girl** although its usually used with positive connotation. A stronger derogatory term would be **basic bitch**. A less frequently used insult I've heard someone refer to a person like that, with emphasis on how much makeup they wear is **Barbie Doll**. In highschool there are different flavors of the fashion obsessed: **preps** wear bright or casual designer clothes such as Holister, American Eagle, etc, whereas **goths and emos** wear dark (mostly black) clothing, makeup and hairstyles. **Basic bros** are guys who often dress like preps or wear excessive sportswear such as team baseball hats, jerseys and most likely pricey footwear such as Nike Jordans even when they themselves do not require sportswear or participate in sports.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I've heard the phrase "they're very label-y" for people who choose products which flaunt designer logos very prominently. As a new coinage I don't know if spelling has standardized;  I can't find it on Google, which points us, equivalently, to Urban Dictionary's "Label wh---". (I don't know how to do the hide-spoilers thing here.)

Answer (score 0):

Getting into niche slang territory:

> [Hypebeast](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hypebeast)

It's commonly associated with the sneakerhead and streetwear fashion circles to describe someone who is incredibly focused on the absolute latest trends. Brand display, either in actual name or iconography (logos, patterns, specific design elements), is essential in signaling how fresh and current your wardrobe is. Typically used in a pejorative manner, but can also been seen as a strong adjective without negative connotation.