# Fashion catchers

Tags: word-request

What do we call people who are addicted in fashion and follow the latest trends? I need some significant words in order to enhance my writing, so please suggest me every single word or noun that is applicable.

Comment: If you're looking specifically for words with a negative undertone, check [this recent question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81628/is-there-a-word-or-slang-word-to-call-a-girl-who-loves-brand-products/).

Comment: *Fashion victim *  or  *fashion conscious *

Comment: A hipster and a trendy

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for [fashionista](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fashionista):

> a designer, promoter, or **follower** of the latest fashions