# When someone loves brands in clothing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I was wondering if you could let me know what is the most natural way to say that **someone loves wearing clothes that have luxury names** like Guccy, Givenchy, Chanel, Dolce and Gabbana, Versace, Armani etc.? I have encountered the following structures, but I have no idea which one is the most natural and idiomatic way to say the same thing in current English:

1. [She always weares brand name clothes/clothing.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81628/is-there-a-word-or-slang-word-to-call-a-girl-who-loves-brand-products)
2. [She always wears designer clothes/clothing.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81628/is-there-a-word-or-slang-word-to-call-a-girl-who-loves-brand-products)
3. [She always wears clothes from a name brand.](https://www.wordreference.com/enes/reverse/brand%20name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them are perfectly acceptable. I'd lean more towards "clothing" on the first two, but there is nothing wrong (as far as I'm aware) with any of these.

To my ear, "brand name/name brand" are both slightly AmE, and in the UK it would be more natural to just say "[**branded**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/branded)".

There is probably a slight difference between a "name brand" and a "designer brand", which is worth being wary of.

> **[Name Brand](https://www.yourdictionary.com/name-brand)**- a well-known brand or trademark or a product bearing such a brand or trademark

Topshop, Levis, Gap - Are all *name* brands, but wouldn't be considered *designer* brands.

In the context, you're using the following definition:

> [**Designer**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/designer): made by a famous or fashionable designer

For this reason, when talking about her specifically wearing *designer* items I would tend towards:

> She always wears designer clothing.

Obviously this is all a little speculative!